# std::stringstream stream operators with binary data

Tags: c++, file-io, stl

I'm working on writing some test cases for a class that will presumably read from an `std::istream` and write to an `std::ostream`. As part of the testing process, I would like to manually create a block of test file data, wrap it in a `std::stringstream`, and then pass it to my class for processing.

I feel like my current solution lacks is lacking despite the fact that it *does* work. I really don't like using those raw write calls with `reinterpret_cast`.

```
std::stringstream file;

uint32_t version = 1;
uint32_t dataSize = 10;
uint32_t recordCount = 3;

file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&version), sizeof(version));
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dataSize), sizeof(dataSize));
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&recordCount), sizeof(recordCount));

myclass.read(file)
```

Is there a way I can use the stream operators to write this data in binary form? I'm hoping for something more akin to the following.

```
std::stringstream file;

uint32_t version = 1;
uint32_t dataSize = 0;
uint32_t recordCount = 3;

file << version << dataSize << recordCount;

myclass.read(file);
```

If I go this route, extracting a number results in `103` which is expected in an ascii context, but I'm obviously trying to avoid serializing my data in that manner.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150843/binary-version-of-iostream

Comment: iostream is not designed with this usage in mind. You may want to consider other libraries, such as boost::spirit::karma or boost::serialize.

Comment: @oakad Or if you do want to use the `>>` and `<<` formats (say because you're not serializing, but reading arbitrary data in a binary format), it's fairly easy to define new stream classes whose "contract" is some sort of binary format, rather than text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your code: when you use the
`reinterpret_cast`, you don't actually know what you are writing
to the stream, so you don't know what you are testing.  If you
want to test how your code reacts to a stream of bytes in
a binary format, you can easily initialize an 
`std::istringstream` with an arbitrary stream of bytes:

```
char bytes[] = { /*...*/ };
std::istringstream( std::string( std::begin( bytes ), std::end( bytes ) ) );
```

(If you don't have C++11, you can easily write your own `begin`
and `end`.)

In this way, you'll know exactly what the bytes are, rather than
depending on the aleas of how your implementation represents any
specific type.

Alternatively: if you're reading and writing binary data, you
may want to define classes which do it, using `>>` and `<<`.
Such classes would be unrelated to `std::istream` and
`std::ostream`, but could logically use `std::ios_base` to
provide support for the conventional error reporting and the
interface to `std::streambuf`.  The class would then have
members something like the following:

```
namespace {

class ByteGetter
{
public:
    explicit            ByteGetter( ixdrstream& stream )
        :   mySentry( stream )
        ,   myStream( stream )
        ,   mySB( stream->rdbuf() )
        ,   myIsFirst( true )
    {
        if ( ! mySentry ) {
            mySB = NULL ;
        }
    }
    std::uint8_t        get()
    {
        int                 result = 0 ;
        if ( mySB != NULL ) {
            result = mySB->sgetc() ;
            if ( result == EOF ) {
                result = 0 ;
                myStream.setstate( myIsFirst
                    ?   std::ios::failbit | std::ios::eofbit
                    :   std::ios::failbit | std::ios::eofbit | std::ios::badbit ) ;
            }
        }
        myIsFirst = false ;
        return result ;
    }

private:
    ixdrstream::sentry  mySentry ;
    ixdrstream&         myStream ;
    std::streambuf*     mySB ;
    bool                myIsFirst ;
} ;
}

ixdrstream&
ixdrstream::operator>>( std::uint32_t&      dest )
{
    ByteGetter          source( *this ) ;
    std::uint32_t       tmp = source.get() << 24 ;
    tmp |= source.get() << 16 ;
    tmp |= source.get() <<  8 ;
    tmp |= source.get()       ;
    if ( *this ) {
        dest = tmp ;
    }
    return *this ;
}
```

(For a maximum of portability, you might wont to avoid the
`uint8_t` and `uint32_t`.  At this level, writing code without
knowing the exact size of the type is a little more difficult,
so if you are certain you'll never have to port to an exotic
system where they may not be defined, it's probably worth saving
yourself the extra work.)

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I was hoping to accomplish my needs without the sort of complexity, but so long as the complexity is isolated and the interface clean, it fits my overall goal. In the end, I decided to use the boost serialization framework over designing my own interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare an operator `<<` for ostreams (so not just string streams, but also file streams).  Something like the following might work (untested), but you might run into troubles with the type (uint32_t):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, uint32_t value)
{
    stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
    return stream;
}

std::stringstream file;
file << version << dataSize << recordCount;
```

**EDIT:**

Because of the type value has, the `<<` operator is already defined.  One alternative would be to declare a new operator `<=`:

```
std::ostream& operator<=(std::ostream& stream, uint32_t value);
file <= version <= dataSize <= recordCount;
```

Both operators operate in a left-to-right fashion, so this might work, maybe not the nicest solution though.

Comment: As you thought, the type does give a little bit of trouble using that solution. `uint32_t` is a typedef for unsigned int on my system and an overload already exists for that type. If I was looking to use a custom class/type, however, that would work very well.

Comment: @vmrob Perhaps you could overload a different operator? see EDIT.

Comment: I think that would work. After evaluating my code, I've decided to take a look at the boost::serialize library. It seems to do what you've suggested by overloading an operator (the `&` specifically) and has many other features I think will work well for my program.

Comment: This violates the basic contracts of `<<`, and should _not_ be done.

Comment: Can you even overload `<=`?

Comment: @JamesKanze Could you elaborate on the contract you're referring to?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes you can overload the `<=` operator. A quick Google search yields this tutorial: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/94-overloading-the-comparison-operators/

Comment: @vmrob The contract for `<<` for `std::ostream` is that the output will be formatted text.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Of course you can overload `<=`.  It's actually rather frequent to do so---any class which supports ordered comparison should do so.  Of course, overloading it to do something other than ordered comparison is flagrant operator abuse.